How to delete a custom connector in Copilot Studio?
I created a custom connector in Copilot Studio as a test. I would now like to delete the connector, however, the delete button is disabled (see screenshot). Does anyone know how to delete?
Link to screenshot

The delete flow seems to be wonky right now.
I was able to do it by removing any dependency that has via the powerpages site.
1)goto https://make.powerpages.microsoft.com
2)select your environment
3)click on solutions and edit your default, or where ever you
published your copilot. it's most likely "Default Solution"
4)The images below show how I was able to do it.
ai plugin selection
show dependencies
remove dependencies

After that you should be able to publish the customizations and your custom copilot connectors will be gone.

I'm all ears if someone else has found a quicker way to do this.
